# How to split first name and last name in two columns when there are 2 last names

Tags: excel, vba

I need to split first name and last name but only need 2 columns and 2 last names is causing an issue

Here is the code I have that uses the text to columns but if someone has 2 last names I need to be able to put both of those into the last name column instead of making three columns.

```vb
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
```

Comment: How do you know they are two last names and not two first names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have names in ColA and you're assuming >2 pieces will assign the "extra" to the last name then:

```
Dim rng As Range, c As Range, v, arr


On Error Resume Next  '<< ignore the error if there's no data in ColA
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
On Error GoTo 0       '<< stop ignoring errors

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If InStr(v, " ") > 0 Then
            arr = Split(v, " ", 2) '<< split only on the first space
            c.Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(arr(0), arr(1)) '<< populate the first and last names
        End If
    Next c
End If
```